# Cannot connect to AWS EC2 instance from Windows 7 using RDP

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, remote-desktop, login, administrator

My laptop is running Windows 7 Home Premium 6.1.7601 SP1.
In AWS I generated a new Key Pair and downloaded the Private key to my laptop.
Ensured that the Security Group used for instance had Port 3389/ RDP open.
I selected a public AMI on AWS and spun up a Windows Server 2008 with SQL Express and IIS (ami-373a735e).
After instance was up and running I "Connected" using the Private Key and generated an Administrator password (saved it) and downloaded a Shortcut File (RDP login).
On the Windows Security/ Login screen I entered the saved password.
Windows Security comes back with "Your credentials did not work. The credentials used to connect to  did not work. Please enter new credentials. Login attempt failed."
No matter how many times I enter the password it comes back with the same error.
I checked all discussion forums and used suggestions before posting.

---

However, when I copy the shortcut file and .pem file over to a Windows 8 laptop during login it showed me a warning indicating that the server certificate was not from a trusted source. I ignored the warning and it logged me in.

Question: Why is Windows 7 not showing me the warning so I can ignore/ bypass and log into to my AWS instance?

Comment: Continuing my research on the net I ended up on http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3922-remote-desktop-connection-rdc-network.html. Here it seems to indicate that Win 7 Home Premium cannot host an RDP connection.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why would your Win 7 machine need to host anything?  You are trying to reach the AWS server from two different *clients*, one of which works, right?